# Wordpress form builder for user submiting post

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, submit

I need to create form for users for submiting posts and I need add custom fields to form. I already have bought http://wpdemo.web-dorado.com/ plugin, but now I see that this plugin can't show in frontend users submitted posts.. Maybe you can say what plugin or which file I need to edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a plugin specific for posts creation via front end, then you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/ plugin. Its PRO version is also available with more features.

There are many other form builder plugins available for posts creation from front end. [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin is a good example for it.

Answer (score 0):

Halo , you can use User Submiter Post , you can get it here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/

I have used it for long time and never get problem, here is the sample i have made :
http://jogjarentalmobil.info/submit

With this plugin you also can modify the form , text tools etc. cool plugin. Hope its can help you